# Unable to add WCF service hosted in azure

Tags: web-services, wcf

I hosted one WCF service on server

```
http://firstdomain.com/WebStorePrice/PickStorePrice.svc
```

which was running on my machine. Now i hosted this to new server as azure service and when trying to add Service reference i am getting the error

There was an error downloading 'https://service.azurewebsites.net/PickStorePrice.svc/$metadata'.
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://service.azurewebsites.net/PickStorePrice.svc'.
There was no endpoint listening at https://service.azurewebsites.net/PickStorePrice.svc that could accept the message. 
This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
 webconfig of wcf service looks like

```
      <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
          <service name="WebStorePrice.PickStorePrice" behaviorConfiguration="cstmServiceConfig">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WebStorePrice.IPickStorePrice"/>
          </service>
        </services>
        <bindings>
          <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="secure">
              <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
              </security>
            </binding>
          </webHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="cstmendpointConfig">
              <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="cstmServiceConfigOnline">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
            <behavior name="cstmServiceConfig">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
      </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the service configuration, our service doesn’t support `Https` protocol since `Azure` docker(Paas)server communicates over Https by default. Therefore we should configure an extra service endpoint for supporting WCF over https.
For Soap style web service, please refer to the below configuration.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
      <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

In regard to WCF Restful style service.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="mybinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="https" bindingConfiguration="mybinding"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.